# imagemagick compose one transparent png(as mask) with one jpg

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have 2 type of images.

Some hundreds of png images with just one color(gray) and some transparent zones then must be transparent even in final result.

Over 30 thousands of jpg images with many size.
I must estrapolate from jpg images the gray zones of png files.

Now i use something like this :

convert JPG_FILE.jpg -resize WIDTH_OF_PNGxHEIGHT_OF_PNG^ -gravity Center -crop WIDTH_OF_PNGxHEIGHT_OF_PNG+0+0 -alpha Set PNG_FILE.png ( -clone 0,1 -alpha Opaque -compose Hardlight -composite ) -delete 0 -compose In -composite RESULT_IMAGE.png

it works very good but its a bit slow

any suggestion for faster execution?

Comment: What is your ImageMagick version and platform? Do you have current libpng and libjpeg installed? What is the size of your RAM? Have you set up your policy.xml file for adequate resources?

Comment: im on ubuntu 18.04 with imagemagick version 6.8 and libpng/libjpeg are installed. I have 16gb of ram on i5 7400, i dont know anything about policy.xml. I think my problem was then i used php with (shell_exec) to convert all these images one by one(in loop) because was more easy to manage what i had done, errors, rename and so on, now i use an little bit different approach using a mix of php and bash scripts to convert all files in one directory. Now im a bit faster, but im still at 0.1sec every convert, with millions convert to go ;(